# php display all row data from mysql table without column name

Tags: php, mysql

I want to display all rows/data from a MySQL table without knowing the column names.

I have the table name but not the column names, and I want to build a grid of the data using the table HTML attribute. I was thinking of using the schema but no idea where to start, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the table structure, use this SQL query:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name;
```

From there you can then make a query that grabs all data from the table and display it as you want.

Answer (score 4):

SELECT * FROM `table_name`;

that should give you all the data including all rows.

Answer (score 0):

it may be helpful for you

```
$response = mysql_query('select * from table_name');
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($response))
{
    foreach($result as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $key.'--'.$value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your select statement you could do "select * from table_name". Then, you go to your for loop() in php and can do more less like this:

`$query = mysqli_query($your_connection_name, $your_sql_query);`

Then, place a while loop:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

        $item_one = $row[0];
        $item_two = $row[1];
        $item_three = $row[2];

? > *//end php*
```

your html code here (table etc)

```
< ? php *//start php again*

} *//end while loop*

?> *//end php*
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an easy task to achieve with the [MYSQLI_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) function as it will put in the db field name as the array key. Take a look at this example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `MyTable`";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $row) {
          foreach($row as $key  => $value) {
             echo '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
         }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

This would print all the tables key and associated values